# How do I access the native calendar on Windows

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am looking to build an app using Apache Cordova and I see there is a cordova-plugin-calendar. But it lists that it is only compatible with Android and iOS. Is there something that will help me access the native calendar on a Windows Phone/Windows 10 machine?

Answer (score 0):

On windows phone you can do it with this method here that uses WinJS:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465480.aspx

You can also use the jQuery mobile date picker which works well on win phone.

**EDIT FROM COMMENTS**

This code is what I used. I only needed to add an event, not read it so you will have to extend his plugin a bit, but the framework is there. nickalchemist.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/… This person packaged it up into a ready to use plug in: github.com/faGH/fa-plugin-calendar

Comment: I am not looking for a way to select a date in a UI. I am looking to actually access the Native Calendar and see the events that may have been stored in it

Comment: Ahh sorry for the confusion.  I had a similar issue to add event functionality in an app.  This code is what I used.  I only needed to add an event, not read it so you will have to extend his plugin a bit, but the framework is there.


https://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/cordova-calendar-plugin-for-windows-phone-8/

This person packaged it up into a ready to use plug in:
https://github.com/faGH/fa-plugin-calendar